# Linking .ui files into C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have done all sorts of research into how to build a GUI in C++. I finally downloaded Qt4Designer because I thought that was my best bet. The problem is that I don't know how to use .ui files in my C++ code. I looked at [Linking a qtDesigner .ui file to python/pyqt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398800/linking-a-qtdesigner-ui-file-to-python-pyqt) and [Difficult linking ui tree widget and header/cpp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922452/difficult-linking-ui-tree-widget-and-header-cpp-files), but I'm not extremely advanced and I don't have a lot of time, so if someone could explain to me exactly how to include the files in my code, that would be great. I admit that can't understand every little detail in that code because I am just starting out in the great world of computer programming. Another part of the problem is that I don't know how to implement the GUI into my code. What that means: If x button is pressed, what does my C++ code do? Please be patient with the question and its naiveness, I'm not an expert and I'm not claiming to be.

Comment: You don't link ui files. You use uic to generate a header for the ui file that you either inherit the object defined in the generated header or use composition.

Comment: ***I'm not extremely advanced and I don't have a lot of time*** Why don't you just use QtCreator. That will be the simplest way. Although it will be hard to create a functional GUI without knowing Qt.

Comment: ***Another part of the problem is that I don't know how to implement the GUI into my code.*** Look up signals and slots in the Qt documentation.

Comment: More that with Qt GUI comes basically all of Qt. To use them, you have to learn Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use QtCreator or you can learn the magic of [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html), which comes with Qt by default. Also you can try [CMake QT tutorial](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Qt) which shows you how to build your QT appls but with a more power tool and feature.

Comment: I would say that learning qmake or CMake would not work well with the time requirement and level of the user.

Comment: There are not shorcuts on programing :p